# Center the bootstrap buttons horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my two buttons center like the one I do with h2 but failed.

Code:

html:

```
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
        <div id="innermain" class="col-xs-12">
          <div><h2>Please choose one button</h2></div>
            <div id="row" class="col-xs-12">
              <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" onclick="">Button 1</div>
              <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" onclick="">Button 2</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
  #kiosk_btn{font-size: 3vh; background-color: #141E26; border:none; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black; margin: 2vh; padding-top:2vh; color:white;}
  #kiosk_btn:active{outline: none; text-decoration: none;}
  #kiosk_btn:focus{outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
  #kiosk_btn:hover{text-decoration: none; background-color: #213140;}
  h2{text-align: center;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/780/)

Comment: replace css
#kiosk_btn {
    background-color: #141e26;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    color: white;
    float: none;
    font-size: 3vh;
    margin: 2vh;
    padding-top: 2vh;
}
..............
    and modify html code using class by giving parent text align center...............

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="row" style="text-align: center;">
              <div onclick="" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" id="kiosk_btn">Button 1</div>
              <div onclick="" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" id="kiosk_btn">Button 2</div>
              </div>

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/783/).

Add two **empty** div with `col-xs-3`. One above two button and one below which fill the  width of `col-xs-12`.

Fiddle uses `class` for setting button CSS property instead of `id`

Side Note:
Make sure to **use only one id** for button or other element.

Comment: `id` should be different for different element. For CSS use class property...Check the updated fiddle..where I have removed `id ` and use class instead...

Answer (score 0):

Your Code contains mulitple Errors:

- wrong div nesting
- don't use (bootstraps) row and col* on the same element
- row is a class in bootstrap, not an id
- use ids (#kiosk_btn) only once or make it a class

That put aside, this will get your desired result:

```
#kiosk_btn{font-size: 3vh; background-color: #141E26; border:none; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black; margin: 2vh; padding-top:2vh; color:white;}
#kiosk_btn:active{outline: none; text-decoration: none;}
#kiosk_btn:focus{outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
#kiosk_btn:hover{text-decoration: none; background-color: #213140;}
.col-xs-12 {text-align: center;}


<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
<div id="innermain" class="col-xs-12">
  <div><h2>Please choose one button</h2></div>
    <div id="row" class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">Button 1</div>
      <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">Button 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw that you have take out the col-xs-3 of my kiosk_btn. But then how would I specify the width of my button?

Comment: Add width:150px; (for example) to your #kios_btn id in css. But in the long run this should be a class since you use it twice.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could look into the CSS property [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp). Which applies a 2D or 3D transformation to an element. This allows you to rotate, scale, move, skew, etc., elements.

In your case you would use `transform: translate(X, Y)` where X and Y should be replaced with either % values, pixels or em values

I've edited your fiddle to match give you a general idea of what to do to achieve this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/780/)

basically what you do is you add a class to your div surrounding your buttons, in this case `.buttons`

The buttons class:

```
.buttons {
   -webkit-transform: translate(20%, 50%);
   -moz-transform:translate(20%, 50%);
   transform:translate(20%, 50%);
}
```

The edited HTML:

```
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
  <div id="innermain" class="col-xs-12">
    <div><h2>Please choose one button</h2></div>
      <div id="row" class="col-xs-12 buttons">
        <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" onclick="">Button 1</div>
        <div id="kiosk_btn" class="btn btn-default col-xs-3" onclick="">Button 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap inbuilt class `text-center` for center alignment of heading and for buttons try to use [grid offset concept](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) of bootstrap.
Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/784/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `form-inline` and `text-center` classes on a form. It is sort of hacky, but works perfectly as long as the screen is 768px and above, otherwise it will degrade when needed. See a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wargog/fo51sutw/)